# Vue.js dinamicaly element and method with params

Tags: функции, vue.js, методы

```js
Vue.component('app-menu', {
 template: '<ul id="menu"><li v-for="menu in menus" v-bind:class="menu.cl">'
   + '<span>{{ menu.name }}</span>'
   + '<ul><li v-for="sub in menu.subs">'
   + '<span v-if="sub.pm" v-on:click="sub.meth(sub.pm)">{{ sub.name }}</span>'
   + '<span v-else v-on:click="sub.meth">{{ sub.name }}</span>'
   + '</li></ul></li></ul>',
 data: function() {
  return {
   menus: [{
    name: 'Name',
    cl: 'submenu',
    subs: [{
      name: 'namesub',
      meth: this.openDic,
      pm: 'hello, world!'
     }]
   }]
  }
 },
 methods: {
  openDic: function(foo) {
   alert(foo);
  }
 }
})

new Vue({
 el: "#appmenu"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="appmenu">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
</div>
```

Then I click on "submenu" method "openDic" return mouseEvent, but I need set my parameter in this method.

ex: ... **meth: this.openDic('myParam')** ...

If I make this code method "openDic" run when load page.

---

При клике по "submenu" метод "openDic" возвращает mouseEvent, но мне нужно передать в этот метод свой параметр.

пример: ... **meth: this.openDic('myParam')** ...

Если я делаю как в примере, метод выполняется сразу после загрузки страницы.

---

**upd:** I fixed code of this post, great thank.

**обн:** исправил пример на верный вариант. благодарю.

Comment: Это русскоязычный сайт, переведите пожалуйста вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
Vue.component('app-menu', {
  template: '<ul id="menu"><li v-for="menu in menus" v-bind:class="menu.cl">' +
    '<span>{{ menu.name }}</span>' +
    '<ul><li v-for="sub in menu.subs">' +
    '<span v-on:click="sub.meth(sub.param)">{{ sub.name }}</span>' +
    '</li></ul></li></ul>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      menus: [{
        name: 'Name',
        cl: 'submenu',
        subs: [{
          name: 'namesub',
          meth: this.openDic,
          param: 'my param'
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openDic: function(foo) {
      alert(foo);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#appmenu"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="appmenu">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Его можно прокинуть так -

```
'<span v-on:click="sub.meth("myParam", sub.name)">{{ sub.name }}</span>'
```